# Dividing two integers to a double in java

Tags: java, int, double, divide

I can see this is a common problem for new programmers, however I didn't succeed in implementing any of the solution to my code. Basically I want to divide w and v, which must be saved to a double variable. But it prints [0.0, 0.0, ... , 0.0]

```
public static double density(int[] w, int[] v){
double d = 0;
    for(L = 0; L < w.length; L++){
        d = w[L]  /v[L];
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Google: integer division. It will give you an integer result with truncation. Write d = (double)w[L]  /v[L];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Comment: If precision is needed, do not use primitive double or its wrapper class. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This line here `d = w[L]  /v[L];` takes place over several steps

```
d = (int)w[L]  / (int)v[L]
d=(int)(w[L]/v[L])            //the integer result is calculated
d=(double)(int)(w[L]/v[L])    //the integer result is cast to double
```

In other words the precision is already gone before you cast to double, you need to cast to double first, so

```
d = ((double)w[L])  / (int)v[L];
```

This forces java to use double maths the whole way through rather than use integer maths and then cast to double at the end

Comment: @SilviuBurcea I'm more trying to represent that it *is* an int

Comment: @Silviu he _explains_ what happens. Not _suggests_ what is there to be done... Big difference

Answer (score 5):

use like following

```
    d = (double) w[L]  /v[L];
```

Answer (score 3):

Actaully `w[L]/v[L]` here both are integers. On the division operation it lost precision and truncated to `integer` value. Then the truncated `integer` is converted to `double`.

The solution would be convert the operand or the divisor or both to a double. Then the division operation would produce a double.

```
d = w[L]/(double)v[L];
```